# Unit test using Xunit framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I'm using Xunit framework to test the following code:

```
public void OpenFileInTxtEditor(string fileName)
{
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        Process.Start(fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not Found");
    }
}
```

I'm new to xUnit and unit testing. Any idea about how to write a test for this method will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [link](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToUse&referringTitle=Home) which is the official documentation. In case when you run into issues, do post the details here so the community can help you figure out.

And in visual studio, you have options for creating a test project or you and add a class library and use it for testing.